# Saving a binary file into OutputStream and back into InputStream

Tags: java, android

I have a binary file that I upload to a cloud storage. I have to write that file into Output stream. Then when I want to download the file, I need to read its content from InputStream. However I don't get the same file. The following is a full working code but with that bug. Excluding cloud and other code because the issue isn't there.

I've gone over Java documentation to construct reading and writing from the streams but I can't find what's the issue - why after writing into Output stream and then reading from Input stream I get different data. Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
public class TActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Create any binary file, e.g., a DB file
  String dbName = "bed872bc-bc8f-4429-8126-070a48c13bdf"; // Just a random UUID
  try (SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)) { ; };

  try {
   // Write the binary file into Output stream
   File originalFile = getDatabasePath(dbName);
   long originalFileLength = originalFile.length();
   ByteArrayOutputStream memoryStreamOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   WriteFromFile(memoryStreamOut, originalFile.toString());

   // Write from the memory stream into the file - expected result is that we end up with identical file content as the original file
   ByteArrayInputStream memoryStreamIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(memoryStreamOut.toByteArray());
   File againTheSameFile = CreateTemporaryFileSafe(this);
   WriteToFile(memoryStreamIn, againTheSameFile);

   // Check whether the files have same size - they should have because they should be identical
   long newFileLength = againTheSameFile.length();
   if (newFileLength != originalFileLength) {
    // it ends up here - they don't equal!
   }
  }
  catch (Exception E) {
   // Log ...
  }
 }

 public static void WriteFromFile(OutputStream outputStream, String filePath) throws Exception {
  try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
   try (FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fileinputstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     writer.write(new String(buffer, 0, length));
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static void WriteToFile(InputStream inputStream, File file) throws Exception {
  try (DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(inputStream)) {
   try (DataOutputStream fileOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 public static File CreateTemporaryFileSafe(Context context) {
  try { return File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "tmp", context.getCacheDir()); }
  catch (IOException E) { return null; }
 }

}
```

Comment: Try to `flush()` the streams because you're not closing any of them so they aren't flushed.

Comment: @Titus - Thank you. I've added flush everywhere it's possible but it's still the same. (Re closing: I'm new to Java but my understanding is that try keyword should be enough and close isn't needed then ?)

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right, now I see that you've used *try-with-resources*. Another thing you could try is to use the same kind of streams. For example a combination of `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` or `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` and read/write the same data type (`byte` arrays or `Strings`).

Comment: `writer.write(new String(buffer, 0, length));`. You should not convert your bytes to strings. Strings are for texts. Do without String class.

Comment: And don't use a `Writer`, for the same reason. Use an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: your binary data is getting corrupted by your (unnecessary) conversions from bytes->string and then string->bytes.  Instead just read it as bytes and then write it as bytes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class Foo {
    private static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
    }

    private static void copyFile(String inputPath, String outputPath) throws IOException {
        try (
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputPath);
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)
        ) {
            copyStream(input, output);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        copyFile(args[0], args[1]);
    }
}
```

Longer answer is that when you convert bytes to a String with String(bytes,0,len), java will do that conversion using the default character set for your JVM (which is probably UTF-8).  But your file *isn't* UTF-8 encoded text, it is random bytes.  And so many of those bytes won't be proper UTF-8.  And Java will silently replace every illegal byte with the unicode 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' which is \uFFFD.

Then when you wrote it back out, you used OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream) which used the default character set to covert your (already corrupted) data back to bytes. Assuming the default encoding is UTF-8, every instance of the replacement character gets replaced with the UTF-8 encoding of that character, which is the bytes 0xef 0xbf 0xbd.  I.e. turning it into three bytes.  And that is why your file size changed: every byte that happened not be legal UTF-8 in the input file gets changed to three bytes in the output file.